# interpreting 私の生徒会に欲しいって会った時から言ってる

Tags: reading-comprehension

MC bumps into the new 生徒会長 after her opening ceremony speech. MC and her are friends since the start of the last school year, but the reader doesn't know what happened between them previous year because of a time skip.

> 生徒会長「ちょうど良かったわねー。じゃあMCも生徒会室に行きましょうか♪」
>
> MC「『じゃあ』じゃないですから。行きませんよ」
>
> 生徒会長「あら、私の生徒会に欲しいって会った時から言ってるのに、そろそろ頷いてもいいんじゃない？」
>
> MC「……それって、会った時にはもう生徒会長になる予定だったんですか」

---

> 生徒会長「perfect timing, well then, why you you come with me to the student council room?♪」
>
> MC「not going」
>
> 生徒会長「oh my, even though you said (or is it I said?) "私の生徒会に欲しいっ" from(?) the time we met... nothing wrong with being obedient right?  」
>
> MC「……about that, when we met you already had plans to be the 生徒会長? 」

I am unsure how exactly to read "私の生徒会に欲しい" in terms of who doing the wanting, what is being wanted here in this quote.

and the use of から to indicate a point in time here is a bit strange for me. 会った時から言う

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of this から is fine. This に after 生徒会 is either a purpose marker or a place marker.

> 私の生徒会に(あなたが)欲しいって言ってるのに
>   I've been saying I want (you) *for/in* my student council

Similar example:

> この会社**に**は彼が必要だ。
>   In this company, he is necessary. / This company needs him.
>
> お土産**に**絵葉書が欲しい。
>   I want a picture postcard as/for a souvenir.

Comment: i see. would something like this be the same usage? 私が男だったらぜひ嫁に欲しい (talking to her friend).  嫁に(あなたが)欲しい?

Comment: @charu Yes, 嫁に欲しい is the same usage as お土産に欲しい.

Answer (score 1):

> あら、私の生徒会に欲しいって会った時から言ってるのに、そろそろ頷いてもいいんじゃない？

Oh? Even though (I've/we've) been telling you that my student council needs you since we first met... Isn't it about time you agreed?

Edit: To people downvoting, I would greatly appreciate feedback as I am still learning myself!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but my guess is this. The OP is struggling with 生徒会に欲しい but you didn't break down this part to explain how it works. Even though 'student council needs you' is a valid translation, it's not what the sentence actually says, and so maybe helps the OP less than you would hope.

Comment: @user3856370 I see, thanks for your feedback.