# に to indicate the role you want something to play?

Tags: particles, particle-に

In Chapter 11 of the Genki textbook, it's stated that に can be used to indicate the role you want something to play. The example sentence given was:

> お土産**に**絵葉書を買いました。

However, I am a bit confused as I was unable to find this particular usage of the に particle elsewhere. Could someone please clarify this issue for me?

Also, I was under the impression that the で particle is used to give context to things. So is it possible to replace に with で in the example sentence above?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17763/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62962/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55456/9831

Comment: @Chocolate The links do a good job of explaining how に works, but I'm also wondering if に can be replaced by で.

Comment: ^ そうなんですよね・・・　Sentences like 「お土産**で**XXをもらった/いただいた」「誕生日/クリスマスプレゼント**で**XXをもらいました」 are actually used by quite a few people.. eg ["プレゼントで * をもらった"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=6TJiXOSLMZCIoASugYyADA&q="プレゼントで+*+をもらった")、["プレゼントで * を買った"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=URIWWpvkNMHz8QXoxb8Y&btnG=Search&q="プレゼントで+*+を買った")

Answer (score 5):

> I was unable to find this particular usage of the に particle elsewhere.

Maybe you could try a monolingual dictionary...? For example, 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> に  〘格助〙
>   ➊㋖資格や見立て、名目などを表す。…として。 [...] 「本を[枕]{まくら}**に**する」「お土産**に**菓子をもらう」「お礼**に**ひとこと」

This に can usually be rephrased as として. It can usually be translated to "as~" or "for~".
本を枕にする -- use a book **as** a pillow
お土産に菓子をもらう -- given sweets **as** a souvenir/gift
お礼にひとこと -- a word **as** expression of gratitude -> say something to show one's gratitude
So.. as your textbook says, the に is used to indicate the role one wants something to play: one makes 本 play the role of 枕, 菓子 the role of 土産, and ひとこと the role of お礼.

Or maybe you could try [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AB/#je-56984):

> に
>   7 〔…として〕as; for
>   親切にしてもらったお礼 (の印) **に**彼らを招待した
>   He invited them 「as a token of his gratitude for [in return for] their kindness.
>   誕生祝い**に**時計をもらった
>   He was given a watch for his birthday.

> I was under the impression that the で particle is used to give context to things. So is it possible to replace に with で in the example sentence above?

Grammatically speaking, I think 「お土産/プレゼント/お礼**に**～」 is the correct usage, and using に sounds more correct to me (of course..), but I occasionally hear/say things like 「お土産**で**XXをもらった」「これ、誕生日のプレゼント**で**もらった」 etc. in casual conversation... (I don't hear/say 「お礼**で**ひとこと」「XXをYYのお礼**で**差し上げる」, though...) So.. I think it'd be probably okay to say 「お土産・プレゼントで～～あげた・もらった」 in casual speech but you should use ～～に in formal speech, writing, exams, etc.

Comment: You say に *usually* can be rephrased as として. When would be a case where you cant?

Comment: @Ringil 「本を枕**に**する」とか・・?（ 「本を枕として使う」would be fine, though.）「お礼にひとこと（述べる、添える etc）」「お礼としてひとこと」 mean the same thing but I think 「お礼に～」 sounds far more natural.

Comment: 『本を枕とする』? Anyways, I was just hoping you would make it clear that the final example would one case where it would be unusual to use として.

Comment: @Rin あ、「本を枕とする」でもいいんですよね。～に in all the examples here has the same meaning as ～として. I think ～に would sound more natural, depending on the context..

Comment: @HING Word order can be quite flexible. (It would depend on the context). お土産に絵葉書を買いました、絵葉書をお土産に買いました both sound good.

Answer (score 0):

に cannot be replaced by で in the above sentence.

It is really hard to pin down the exact translation of に because it has many, **many** usages. As a rule of thumb though, に emphasizes the goal / end point of an action. You could formulate it as *purpose* in your case. Another similar example would be:

- 父の遺産は家のリフォームに使いたいと思います。I want to use my father's heritage in order to renovate my house (goal)

On the other hand, で means "to use" and / or emphasizes the usage of something as a means to an end. For instance:

- ２時間で走りきった。I "used" two hours to run the entire distance
- お金で買いました。I used money to buy it.

As you can see from the last example, using で in お土産**で**ハガキを買いました sounds like you *used* souvenirs *in order to* buy postcards...